# CoreTelephony is not available when building for watchOS - when adding watch app target to ios app project

Tags: swift, xcode, watchos

This is a new error...I just recently added a watch target to my ios app and when to build...I was able to silence a myriad of other errors that came up, but this one will not go away:

CoreTelephony is not available when building for watchOS

What does it even mean? It is not referencing an error in my code, but a file in derived data...I tried to clean my build folder several times, but the error just won't go away. Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this error was due to the incompatibility with Firebase. Once I removed firebase from my files and refactored, everything worked again...kind of a bummer but hopefully firebase will support it one day :/